# Orchard CMS - determining if Model is valid in Content Item Driver

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

In my instance of Orchard, I have a custom content type which has a custom content part. In the "editor driver" for the content part, I need to check to see if the container content item is valid (i.e. passes validation).

The normal ModelState won't work here because of how Orchard works - and I can determine if the content part is valid, but I need to know about the entire content item (there are other content parts within the content item).

I know there are ways to execute code once a content part is published / created using lifecycle events (http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-content-handlers), but there's no way (that I know of) to pass those events information.

Basically, I need to execute a method if the content item is valid, and I need to pass the method information contained within the ViewModel.

There may be (and probably is) a better way to do this, but I'm struggling to find a way within Orchards framework.

sample code:

```
//POST
protected override DriverResult Editor(EventPart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
{
    var viewModal = new EventEditViewModel();

    if (updater.TryUpdateModel(viewModal, Prefix, null, null))
    {
        part.Setting = viewModal.Setting;
    }

    //here's where I need to check if the CONTENT ITEM is valid or not, for example
    if (*valid*)
    {
        DoSomething(viewModal.OtherSetting);
    }

    return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
}
```

Note: I am using Orchard version 1.6.

Comment: Can you give more details about the scenario? Why do you need to do that?

Answer (score 4):

No easy way to do that from inside a driver, I'm afraid. Too early. You can access other parts by doing `part.As<OtherPart>`, but those may or may not be updated yet at this point.

You may try utilizing handlers and `OnPublishing`/`OnPublished` (and other) events like this:

```
        OnPublishing<MyPart>((ctx, part) =>
        {
            // Do some validation checks on other parts
            if (part.As<SomeOtherPart>().SomeSetting == true)
            {
                notifier.Error(T("SomeSetting cannot be true."));
                transactions.Cancel();
            }
        });
```

where `transactions` is `ITransactionManager` instance, injected in ctor.

If you need more control, writing your own controller for handling item updates/creates is the best way to go.

In order to do that (assuming you already have your controller in place), you need to use handler `OnGetContentItemMetadata` method to point Orchard to use your controller instead of the default one, like this:

```
        OnGetContentItemMetadata<MyPart>((context, part) =>
        {
            // Edit item action
            context.Metadata.EditorRouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary {
            {"Area", "My.Module"},
            {"Controller", "Item"},
            {"Action", "Edit"},
            {"id", context.ContentItem.Id}};

            // Create new item action
            context.Metadata.CreateRouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary {
            {"Area", "My.Module"},
            {"Controller", "Item"},
            {"Action", "Create"});
        });
```

Comment: +1 from me, you solved my problem too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242539/orchard-connected-parts/19269461#19269461  thank you